# Listar arquivos de diretório em uma table usando php

Tags: php, html

Tenho este código php e html que lista arquivos de uma pasta, mas gostaria de colocar os resultados em uma table, mas para cada linha está sendo repetido o título da coluna, o DirectoryIterator consegui resolver, segue o código atualizado:

```
   <head>
<style>
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>  

<?php


$path = "arquivos/";


echo "<h2>Lista de Arquivos:</h2><br />";
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {
        if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

    echo "<table>

    <tr>
    <th>Nome</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href='".$path.$fileInfo->getFilename() ."'>".$fileInfo->getFilename()."</a><br /></td>
    </tr>

</table>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>

<?php
```

Comment: Primeiro, remova o `<tr>` que possui o nome da coluna do laço de repetição se não quer que ele se repita; segundo, pesquise sobre `DirectoryIterator` do PHP.

Comment: Resolveu não! @AndersonCarlosWoss

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss o DirectoryIterator consegui entender e resolvi, mas o nome da coluna continua repetindo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você irá criar apenas uma `table` e uma linha de títulos, então não pode repetir isso, como também não pode repetir o fechamento da `table` (`</table>`).

Exemplo:

```
<?php

$path = "arquivos/";

// Título
echo "<h2>Lista de Arquivos:</h2><br />";

// Abre a tabela, cria títulos
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr> <th>Nome</th> </tr>";

// Loop que gera registros
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $fileInfo) {

    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;

    // Imprime linhas de registros
    echo "<tr>
            <td>
                <a href='".$path.$fileInfo->getFilename() ."'>".$fileInfo->getFilename()."</a><br/>
            </td>
          </tr>";
}

// Fecha a tabela
echo "</table>";

?>
```

Comment: vou testar aqui, vlw

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: @MiguelSilva o mais importante é você entender ! Se tiver dúvidas, só avisar ! :)

Comment: é possível adicionar mais uma coluna para mostrar tamanho do arquivo?

Comment: Vou tentar adicionar

Comment: Tem sim, cria dentro do `<tr>` de título, o `<th>Tamanho</th>`, e cria uma coluna `<td>` ao lado da que já tem. O tamanho, você pode usar o [filesize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filesize.php).

Comment: Muito Obrigado! vlw mesmo.

Comment: desculpe, não consegui fazer imprimir o tamanho, consigo adicionar a coluna e tal, mas não consegui fazer imprimir o tamanho, se puder me ajudar. vlw

Comment: @MiguelSilva Cria uma pergunta nova, assim facilita eu ver o que fez, como está, e como poderá fazer... fazer pelo comentário é ruim, e nem é o correto ! ;)

Comment: Ok, vou fazer isso

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76932/discussion-between-miguel-silva-and-rbz).